# Conditional Refresh of Pivot Table in Excel

Tags: excel, pivot

I have an Excel file with a data set in 'sheet1' that is refreshed every hour. On 'sheet2' I have 24 pivot tables (and corresponding chart), one for each hour. For each pivot table (e.g. 15:00), I want the pivot table to refresh once the data of hour 15 is downloaded. Then, it needs to remain unchanged for 24 hours (as the data refresh overrules all data of previous hour) and update again when the data of hour 15 of the next day is downloaded.

So every hour, the next pivot table in line should be refreshed, while all others remain unchanged, and start again with the first one when a new day has started.

Currently I have set it up like:

- In cell A1: Hour of last data as number (e.g. 15, 16, etc.)
- VBA code for 'sheet2':

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Workbooks("Filename").Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1") = 15 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Workbooks("Filename").Sheets("sheet2").PivotTables("Pivot1500").RefreshTable
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End If

End Sub
```

For now I only have VBA code for hour 15, to try this out. But unfortunately, this either results in now refresh of the pivot table, refreshing all other pivot tables as well, or refreshing pivot table 'Pivot1500' even when data of following hours is downloaded and cell A1 is no longer 15.

Any suggestions on how to make this work?